# Rails ActiveRecord Transaction does not finish

Tags: ruby, activerecord, transactions

I have a Transaction for a batch insert/update block and all of sudden it stopped working.
The are no errors or exception risen and it seems like Rails stops just before the `end` of the Transaction blog so the methods does not return.
I restarted both MySQL and the system but still.

Comment: Please consider clicking the check mark next to questions that were answered satisfactorily. This lets people know their work is appreciated, and increases your "Accept" rate which encourages people to answer future questions.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it was the delayed option of the thinking sphinx indexing that caused the problem.